# Nsight Compute can not non-interactive Profiler in Windows

Tags: cuda, nsight, nsight-compute

when i try to connect to localhost and non-interactive profiler a sample kernel function, it always shows below.

however, i can use interactive profiler just as fine.

```
Launched process: ncu.exe (pid: 25384)
E:/NsightCompute/target/windows-desktop-win7-x64/ncu.exe 
--config-file off --export D:/Programming/CUDA/1.ncu-rep 
--force-overwrite D:/Programming/CUDA/1.exe
Launch succeeded.
Profiling...
Process terminated.
The profiler returned an error code: 3221226505 (0xc0000409)
```

i have try to run Nsight Compute in admin, didn't work.
what is more strange that i can use the feature normally in WSL's Nsight Compute.

Comment: Which version of Nsight Compute are you using?

Comment: the version is 2023.3.1, and the cuda is 12.3

Comment: I'd suggest asking the NVIDIA'ns about this error code, to see what the complaint actually is. Consider the [NVIDIA forums](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/), or maybe @RobertCrovella could shed light on this. Also, if you run that executable without the profiler - does it exit successfully? And have you tried an executable which does nothing and quits?